# backports_abc not compatible with Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I'm trying to install Python 3.6 but see the following:

```
Tucker:~/workspaces/scripts/verify>  conda install python=3.6  
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - backports_abc -> python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I can uninstall `backports_abc` but it seems to take a lot with it.

Is that the correct step?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the solution here is to start from scratch. anaconda.com gives you a choice of a 3.6 version or a 2.7 version. Switching looks like it requires a reinstall.